# Monitor flickering in gray areas when running newer games

Tags: display, graphics-card, lcd

i really can't seem to wrap my head around this one. I basically bought a new PC (almost new, anyway, since i'm using the graphics card and hdd from my old one) and when i run any newer game (battlefield 4, bioshock infinite etc) i keep getting these horizontal flickering lines, mostly visible in grayer areas of the screen.

This is also noticeable across the whole screen, so the desktop gets these lines across it if the game is open in windowed mode as well. It doesn't seem to happen in any older games like Deus Ex or something that isn't graphically intensive like Hearthstone.

I don't think it's a temperature-related issue since my gpu doesn't go over 60C and the effect becomes apparent instantly, and when exiting a game disappears just as fast. Probably worth noting is that my monitor is connected via a vga cable with a dvi adapter on the graphics card's end and that my monitor only supports a vga input.

I also tried hooking the pc up to my tv with both vga and hdmi cables and the effect didn't seem to occur there, however when i tried it on a friend's monitor (vga cable) i got the same effect only slightly less pronounced, hence my confusion. I'm really stumped on this one, as before the pc upgrade everything was working fine, at least i managed to play through bioshock infinite without noticing any hitches.

Comment: Are you using amd?

Answer (score 0):

If it worked fine on your old box chances are it is compatibility/driver related.  Make sure your Mobo and GPU drivers are up to date.

Comment: Mobo drivers are freshly downloaded from the manufacturer website and as for the gpu drivers, i tried both the latest release and beta versions from nvidia. If it were a driver issue i would also be expecting the same problem to occur when i tested it on the tv.

Comment: Sorry missed the TV try comment...can you provide what your components are, might assist in trouble shooting.  It would be useful to know what your mobo, gpu and processor are at a minimum.

Comment: Mobo is a Z87X-SLI, gpu GTX660, processor i5-4670K. I thought about next trying to hook up a monitor with a dvi input, since i read some people fixed similar issues that way. However i'm still stumped as to why vga isn't working anymore since it's the same video card i've been using for a few months now.

Comment: Do you have extra components laying around?  If you have a GPU you can swap in and test that would help isolate.  My hunch is it is tied to that piece.  Have you done any customizing to your GPU settings?  Like refresh rate for example?

Comment: I haven't modified anything like that, no. It probably would be a good idea to check with another gpu indeed, though what still bugs me is that this doesn't manifest when i hook it up to the tv. If the gpu was the problem i would not expect it to be picky as to what it's connected to. I think i'll try slotting my gpu in another pc as well in the mean time and see what happens just in case, nothing here seems to make sense.

Comment: I've tried switching the gpu and the issue was still present. It has been suggested it might be signal interference in the cable since i'm using a vga connection. Still trying to find a monitor with a dvi input to test on.

Comment: After trying a dvi connection, I gave up and just decided to buy a new monitor. Digital signals seems to work just fine. Still can't explain why vga worked on my tv but not any monitor, one of life's great mysteries, i guess.

Comment: That is bizarre, glad you're up and running.